# How to filter all list which a key has a specific value/values from lists of dict in Ansible?

Tags: jquery, json, ansible, jinja2

I would like to return the lists of a key('minio_vf') has a specific value(True) from the input data. So I used selectattr('minio_vf', '==' ,True) filter to get all list.

Input Data #1 ('minio_vf' key is included):

```
[{'bus_info': 'b1:00.0', 'pf_driver': 'ice', 'flow_configuration': True, 'default_vf_driver': 'iavf', 'sriov_numvfs': 32, 'minio_vf': True, 'sriov_vfs': {'vf_30': 'vfio-pci', 'vf_31': 'vfio-pci'}}, 
{'bus_info': 'b1:00.1', 'pf_driver': 'ice', 'default_vf_driver': 'iavf', 'flow_configuration': True, 'sriov_numvfs': 32, 'minio_vf': True, 'sriov_vfs': {'vf_30': 'vfio-pci', 'vf_31': 'vfio-pci'}}]
```

Expected Result:

```
[{'bus_info': 'b1:00.0', 'pf_driver': 'ice', 'flow_configuration': True, 'default_vf_driver': 'iavf', 'sriov_numvfs': 32, 'minio_vf': True, 'sriov_vfs': {'vf_30': 'vfio-pci', 'vf_31': 'vfio-pci'}}, 
{'bus_info': 'b1:00.1', 'pf_driver': 'ice', 'default_vf_driver': 'iavf', 'flow_configuration': True, 'sriov_numvfs': 32, 'minio_vf': True, 'sriov_vfs': {'vf_30': 'vfio-pci', 'vf_31': 'vfio-pci'}}]
count: 2
```

Input Data #2 ('minio_vf' key is **NOT included)**:

```
[{'bus_info': 'b1:00.0', 'pf_driver': 'ice', 'flow_configuration': True, 'default_vf_driver': 'iavf', 'sriov_numvfs': 32, 'sriov_vfs': {'vf_30': 'vfio-pci', 'vf_31': 'vfio-pci'}}, 
{'bus_info': 'b1:00.1', 'pf_driver': 'ice', 'default_vf_driver': 'iavf', 'flow_configuration': True, 'sriov_numvfs': 32, 'sriov_vfs': {'vf_30': 'vfio-pci', 'vf_31': 'vfio-pci'}}]
```

Expected Result:

```
[]
count: 0
```

My code:

```
---
- name: data test
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    data_list1:
      [
        {
          'bus_info': 'b1:00.0', 
          'pf_driver': 'ice', 
          'minio_vf': True, 
          'sriov_vfs': {'vf_30': 'vfio-pci', 'vf_31': 'vfio-pci'}
         }, 
        {
          'bus_info': 'b1:00.1',
          'pf_driver': 'ice',
          'minio_vf': True,
          'sriov_vfs': {'vf_30': 'vfio-pci', 'vf_31': 'vfio-pci'}
        }
      ]

    data_list2:
      [
        {
          'bus_info': 'b1:00.0', 
          'pf_driver': 'ice', 
         }, 
        {
          'bus_info': 'b1:00.1',
          'pf_driver': 'ice',
        }
      ]
 
  tasks:
  - name: get the list
    set_fact:
      minio_list1: "{{ data_list1 | selectattr('minio_vf', '==', True) }}"

  - name: print the list
    debug:
      msg: "{{ minio_list1 }}"

  - name: count the list
    debug:
      msg: "{{ minio_list1 | length }}"

  - name: get the list
    set_fact:
      minio_list2: "{{ data_list2 | selectattr('minio_vf', '==', True) }}"

  - name: print the list
    debug:
      msg: "{{ minio_list2 }}"

  - name: count the list
    debug:
      msg: "{{ minio_list2 | length }}"
```

When it has correct key, it works fine. However, when it has no key, it gives the error:

Output:

```
PLAY [data test] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [get the list] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [print the list] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

[{'bus_info': 'b1:00.0', 'pf_driver': 'ice', 'minio_vf': True, 'sriov_vfs': {'vf_30': 'vfio-pci', 'vf_31': 'vfio-pci'}}, {'bus_info': 'b1:00.1', 'pf_driver': 'ice', 'minio_vf': True, 'sriov_vfs': {'vf_30': 'vfio-pci', 'vf_31': 'vfio-pci'}}]

TASK [count the list] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {}

MSG:

2

TASK [get the list] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'minio_vf'

The error appears to be in '/home/spark1/test2.yml': line 47, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


  - name: get the list
    ^ here


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I tried to use json_query like the below, but it didn't work either:

```
 - name: set data   set_fact:
     num_of_minio_vfs: "{{ data | json_query(the_var) }}"
   vars:
     the_var: "[?minio_vf==True]"
```

What would be the right way to return empty list when it doesn't have a key?

Comment: [edit] the question and provide [mre].

Comment: @VladimirBotka sorry for the source, updated the source code and output

Answer (score 0):

Given the lists

```yaml
  l1:
    - {k1: A0, k2: true, k3: C}
    - {k1: A1, k2: true, k3: C}
  l2:
    - {k1: A0, k3: C}
    - {k1: A1, k3: C}
```

create a list with the default values

```yaml
  ld:
    - {k2: false}
```

Then, the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {{ lx|to_yaml }}
          count: {{ lx|length }}
      loop:
        - "{{ l1 }}"
        - "{{ l2 }}"
      vars:      
        lx: "{{ ld|product(item)|map('combine')|selectattr('k2') }}"
```

gives (abridged) the expected output. Use the filter *to_json* instead of *to_yaml* if you insist on JSON

```yaml
  msg: |-
    - {k1: A0, k2: true, k3: C}
    - {k1: A1, k2: true, k3: C}
    count: 2

  msg: |-
    []
    count: 0
```